# SQL Count days Between Two Dates from One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the number of days between two dates that are present in the same column! when the ID is are same.

Here is a sample below...

```
ID       Date    
a       01/12/2024    
a       01/13/2024    
b       01/12/2024    
b       01/20/2024    
b       01/25/2024    
c       01/12/2024    
c       01/12/2024
```

Counted Days should appear in new column.

```
ID       Date        Days 
a       01/12/2024    0   
a       01/13/2024    1   
b       01/12/2024    0   
b       01/20/2024    8   
b       01/25/2024    5   
c       01/12/2024    0   
c       01/12/2024    0
```

Any help is much appreciated (y).

Comment: Perhaps `DATEDIFF(d,Date,LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using window function [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to retrieve previous rows and `DATEDIFF` function to calculate the difference in days between two dates:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(day, LAG(dt, 1, dt) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt), dt) as Days 
FROM mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EQnBWcT4)

Comment: Thanks for the respond "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier as am using SQL-server

Comment: Could you check my recent edit

Answer (score 0):

Does this example help?

```
create table #temp(

    id varchar(10) null,
    theDate datetime null
    )
    go

    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('a','20240112')
    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('a','20240113')
    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('b','20240112')
    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('b','20240120')
    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('b','20240125')
    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('c','20240112')
    insert into #temp (id, theDate) values ('c','20240112')


select d.id, d.theDate, case when  case when DATEDIFF(day,LAG(d.theDate) over (order by d.id, d.theDate),d.theDate) < 0 then 0 else  DATEDIFF(day,LAG(d.theDate) over (order by d.id, d.theDate),d.theDate) end is null then '' else case when DATEDIFF(day,LAG(d.theDate) over (order by d.id, d.theDate),d.theDate) < 0 then 0 else  DATEDIFF(day,LAG(d.theDate) over (order by d.id, d.theDate),d.theDate) end end Days
from #temp d


id  theDate                 Days
a   2024-01-12 00:00:00.000 0
a   2024-01-13 00:00:00.000 1
b   2024-01-12 00:00:00.000 0
b   2024-01-20 00:00:00.000 8
b   2024-01-25 00:00:00.000 5
c   2024-01-12 00:00:00.000 0
c   2024-01-12 00:00:00.000 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier as am using SQL-server